# How to print particular column data as user input column names in python?

Tags: python, pandas, input

I have the following table:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 0 | 22 | 33 | 5 | 7 |
| bb | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 234 |
| cc | 9 | 2 | 82 | 0 | 66 |
| dd | 5 | 27 | 890 | 66 | 184 |

How do I print the table, such that, the output contains only the data that user entered. (The user enters the column name as input and the output should contain that columns data along with Column1 by default).

**For example:**
If the user enters the input as Column 2, Column4, Column5. The **output** should be the following:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 0 | 33 | 5 |
| bb | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| cc | 9 | 82 | 0 |
| dd | 5 | 890 | 66 |

How do I do that in python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user should enter columns in comma seperated manner like below:

```
x=input("Enter the required columns:").split(',')

Enter the required columns:a,b


df[['Column1']+x]
df
```